# Get , Set ) can't get average result

Tags: java

I have a get/set program, and I'm trying to get the average result, but I always get  0.0 instead.

- The program has 5 instances, and 1 return method for each
- The main has 2 user input, and 3 grade numbers

Account class:

```
public class Account {
    private String name1;
    private String name2;
    private double grade1;
    private double grade2;
    private double grade3;
    private double average;

    public Account(String a1, String a2, double b1, double b2, double b3) {
        name1 = a1;
        name2 = a2;
        grade1 = b1;
        grade2 = b2;
        grade3 = b3;
    }

    public void setName1(String a1) {
        name1 = a1;
    }

    public void setName2(String a2) {
        name2 = a2;
    }

    public void setGread1(double b1) {
        grade1 = b1;
    }

    public void setGread2(double b2) {
        grade2 = b2;
    }

    public void setGread3(double b3) {
        grade3 = b3;
    }

    public String getName1() {
        return name1;
    }

    public String getName2() {
        return name2;
    }

    public double getgrade1() {
        return grade1;
    }

    public double getgrade2() {
        return grade2;
    }

    public double getgrade3() {
        return grade3;
    }

    public void setAverage(double ave) {
        average = ave;
    }

    public double getAverage() {
        return average = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%-5s %2s the average is: %5s%% ", name1, name2,
                average);
    }
}
```

Main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the  frist  and last name of student" );

    String inf=in.nextLine();
    String infs=in.nextLine();

    Account account= new Account(inf,infs,5,6,7);    
    System.out.print(account);
}
```

I  fed up  of trying to solve it , so please help me.

Comment: I'm fed up reading unindented and blank lines of code. :P

Comment: Only post the relevant code!

Comment: Use an IDE, like Eclipse.

Comment: Or like NetBeans perhaps ;)

Answer (score 0):

You never *assign* any value to `average` so it keeps its default value of `0.0`. Move this assignment from `getAverage`

```
average = (grade1 + grade2 + grade3) / 3;
```

to your constructor. Getter and setters typically do not contain this type of logic.

Comment: And remove the unnecessary setters and instance attributes like setAverage and average, and format the code, and...

Comment: Agreed, should really be no logic in any setter/getter other than assignment/return

Comment: I assigned it  here  " Account account= new Account(inf,infs,5,6,7);" I will try to assign it   inside the class  .  thank you for relying

Comment: There's no assignment to `average` in the constructor. You have a `getAverage` method which you never call. As a result the value of `average` in your `toString` method equals `0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

What is the use of [getters and setters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters) if you have already have done initialization in constructor.

Any ways, your public  `Account(String a1 ,String a2 ,double b1,double b2,double b3)`

should look something like this:

```
public  Account(String a1 ,String a2 ,double b1,double b2,double b3) {

name1=a1;
name2=a2;
grade1=b1;
grade2=b2;
grade3=b3;
average=getAverage();

}
```

As suggested by @Reimeus , You never assign any value to `average`.